# How to combine thymeleaf with element ui？

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, element-ui

Recently my boss asked me to complete a view use thymeleaf, this view contains an input box has autocomplete function, and my boss expect me to accomplish this feature using element ui input box which has autocomplete function, so I'm wondering that how can I combine thymeleaf with element ui so that I could use it's conponent.
Please help solve problem, I'll be so grateful for that.

Comment: You should be using jQuery (or similar) AJAX functionality to get the autocomplete data from the server side (asyncronously) and render the response data in a javascript function. There are tons of examples over the web. You can follow this https://edwin.baculsoft.com/2017/12/create-a-simple-autocomplete-textfield-using-spring-mvc-jquery-easyautocomplete-and-hibernate/ By the way Thymeleaf has nothing to do with this autocomplete thing, just jQeury, Spring MVC Controller and Return Data. Thymeleaf may need an extra bit in JavaScript part maybe.

Comment: So thymeleaf is just a template like jsp??

Comment: By the way, I want to know that if I can accomplish the autocomplete function by myself?? because I know that Element ui offer a kind of input box which can set suggestion like the code following. 

<el-autocomplete
      class="inline-input"
      v-model="state1"
      :fetch-suggestions="querySearch"
      placeholder="please input message"
      @select="handleSelect"
    ></el-autocomplete>

Comment: Yes thymeleaf is just a templating engine. And yes you can implement the autocomplete input box function by yourself without using a ready component. You just need a Controller Method on the server side, an input box and a JS AJAX call to get the data and render it accordingly

Comment: Okay I seem know how to solve this problem.And I'm very new in javaweb, so I could not comprehend and describe those tecnology like thymeleaf correctly, so thank you so much for anwsering my question so patiently~